# Geoprocessing breaks my data links after upgrade?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layers, file-geodatabase, arcgis-10.3

I've had this problem all day, and it's happened before, too. I am running desktop 10.3.1 and want to produce a very simple buffer from a single parcel. The output is assigned to the same .gdb that the buffer output is assigned to. When I run the buffer, every other feature class in the map from that .gdb breaks the data link and I end up with a map full of red exclamation points, except for the most recent layer.
Occasionally this happens even when all I am doing is exported selected features into their own layer. Has anybody else experienced this?

Comment: No, that's weird. I think you'll have to lodge that with Esri support. Is your GDB and map version 10.3.1? Were they created before? Perhaps upgrading the database to the current version and saving the MXD might help but it sounds more fundamental than that... time to use Esri support.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the default location into which outputs of your geoprocessing tools are written, has been reset by the upgrade.

Next time you run a tool pay careful attention to the workspace into which the output is being written, and check that against the source of any layer that you are expecting it to overwrite.